how to search in an array of referenced objects in mongodb
In this problem, I have two Collections: Users and Chats. Below is the Schema for both the Collection
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {type:String, required:true},
        email: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
        password: {type:String, required:true},
        picture: {type:String,  default:"https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg"}
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)

const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        chatName: {type: String, trim: true},
        isGroupChat: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        users: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User"
        }],
        latestMessage:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"Message"
        },
        groupAdmin:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User"
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)

I want to search a chat with the name of the user. I am able to acheive this with the below query.
db.chats.aggregate([
            {"$unwind":"$users"},
            {
                "$lookup":{
                    "from":"users",
                    "localField":"users",
                    "foreignField":"_id",
                    "as":"user"
                }
            },
            {
                "$match" : { "user.name": { "$regex":"pam", "$options": "i" } },
               
                        
                
            }
        ])

The only problem in the above query is that it gives me all chats where User with the name "pam" is present but I only want chats where the current logged in user is also present as one of the two users.
Please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Have you tried to use a $lookup sub-pipeline to limit the lookup result?

As @ray said, use the lookup-pipeline and put your $match clause there. Also, you don't need to $unwind users before the lookup. When passed an array, the lookup will apply to each thing in the array.

Thanks @ray I looked at the documentation for sub-pipelines and achieved the output with some more tweaks.

Thanks @aneroid for pointing out that using unwind, it was redundant and I realized that after reading about it

@NikitaJha If you want, post an answer to your own question with the updated pipeline. Otherwise, this question should be closed/deleted.
